# Calling a jsp page through javascript call

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, jsp

Script code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function checkStatus(){
var productid=$("#productCode").val();
var Email=$("#productEmail").val();
$.ajax({ 
    type:'post', 
    data : {Email : Email},
    url:'', 
    }).success(function(status) { 
    success(status); 
    }); 
}

function success(status) {
alert("data is" +status);
    if (status != null && status===true) {
        alert('Success');
        $('#showMessage').show();
        $('#showbecomepartnerMessage').hide();
    } else {
        alert('Error');
        $('#showbecomepartnerMessage').show();
        $('#showMessage').hide();
    }

}
</script>
```

html messages code :(which i want to display in another jsp)

```
<div id="showpartMessage" class="2" style="display: none;">
                                <h5 style="color: #1ea59e;">Email not saved</h5>
</div>

<div id="showMessage" class="2" style="display: none;">
                                <h5 style="color: #1ea59e;">Email is saved</h5>
</div>
```

I have an ajax call which returns me true or false value.According to this true or false value i will be showing and hiding the div messages.

I have a jsp layout in which different jsp(components) pages are clubbed(integrated).So my requirement is i want to make a javascript call from a jsp page to another jsp page without opening any new window.
Is it possible??any help would be appreciated.

Note : Both the jsp pages are inside same layout ie; clubbed in one another jsp layout.

Comment: clubbed means, `a.jsp` is includes in `b.jsp`?

Comment: @Satya No a.jsp and b.jsp are together in c.jsp...

Comment: so you makes `ajax` call in `c.jsp`?

Comment: no i make ajax calls to controller...and get some true or false value...so according to that i have to display the message...so i want to display that message in another jsp by calling through javascript function

Comment: if you make a `ajax` call in `c.jsp` the result should be displayed in some other jsp page `a.jsp` its already included in `c.jsp`. is it correct.

Answer (score 1):

1) **First example**

Opening the JSP page in a separate popup window using JavaScript function - window.open(); eg: window.open(MyPage.jsp)

2) **Second example**

```
<script language="JavaScript"> 
function updateStats(){ 
var jspcall="url.jsp" 
window.location.href=jspcall 
} 
</script>
```

3) **Third example**

```
function getInput()
{
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",    
        url: "jsp/Ajax.jsp",
        data:"name=john",         
          success: function(success) {

          }
        });
}
```

Comment: i want to call jsp inside success function...and without opening any window....refresing page is ok...

Comment: success : function(data) {
     windows.location.href='/myJSP.jsp;
   });

Comment: its ok but i want to print a succes message and fail message according to the value in that myJSP.jsp is that possible??

Comment: Please try this  window.location.href ="/myJSP.jsp?PostData1=SomeThing1&PostData2=SomeThing2"; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252184/window-location-href-send-multiple-parameters-asp-net-mvc